# Intermittent Freezing of External Display on Ubuntu 22.04 with Dual-Screen Setup

Tags: 22.04, multiple-monitors, display-resolution, hdmi, asus

I recently encountered an issue with my new laptop (ASUS VivoBook 16X F1605, 12th Gen Intel, running Ubuntu 22.04 as a dual-boot) where my external display freezes intermittently. Here are the details:

**Laptop Specs:** ASUS VivoBook 16X F1605 (12th Gen Intel) with a native 16:10 resolution. [Laptop Specs Link](https://shop.asus.com/us/90nb10n3-m004m0-vivobook-16x-f1605-12th-gen-intel.html)

**External Monitor:** 16:9 resolution, connected via HDMI.

**Issue Description:** The external monitor freezes randomly while the laptop screen remains operational. I can still interact with applications by moving them to the laptop screen using the keyboard. However, when I unplug and then replug the HDMI cable, both screens freeze momentarily, then go black, and subsequently return to normal. Additionally, I've had issues with Chrome having odd lag issues that seemingly were resolved (it hasn't happened yet in a couple days) by disabling Chrome's Hardware Acceleration feature.

**Previous Experience:** I did not encounter this issue with Ubuntu 20.04 on my old laptop.

Hopefully I've given enough info for someone to have any insight and set me in the correct path, but I'm available to quickly reply with extra info. Thanks in advance for your help!

**Edit for more info:** I have uBlock Origin and it *seems* that the screen only freezes when Chrome and VS Code are open. I also notice tabs like Calendar with thousands of traffic blocked by uBlock and hundreds of blocks on Notion and GCP console tabs.